# CSS table using colspan and rowspan - better way to apply class to siblings?

Tags: html, css, css-tables, siblings

Here's my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UjAQf/102/

Is there a better way to apply the "pickBody" to each table row instead of inserting the class directly in HTML like I am doing?  For example, "for each table row sibling apply this style."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by styling all the rows the same...

```
.geniusPicks table tr {
    /* Your styles here */
}
```

Then for rows with other classes, override any undesired style elements in each class definition.

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

http://jsfiddle.net/UjAQf/105/

Comment: great, thanks! so is this the way you'd personally go about implementing this style?  or is my original approach fine?

Comment: Surreal Dreams is right, but you would need to modify a few others things in your case. You can remove the `tbody` in `.geniusPicks table tbody tr td {}` in my example. The other classes don't seem to always override `.geniusPicks table tr` i.e. the addition of `!important`